# Utilizar variáveis da URL no código PHP

Tags: php, url

Imaginem que possuo uma URL tagueada, por exemplo: https://meusite.com.br?utm_source=StackOverflow.

Esse seria o básico do tagueamento, tem também os parâmetros utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign, utm_term e por fim utm_content.

Fiz um código para puxar esses parâmetros e criar variáveis (pois vou utilizá-las em outro lugar). O problema é que se a URL está com TODOS os parâmetros o código funciona normalmente. Agora, se falta um por exemplo ele dá erro. Precisaria que ele simplesmente ignorasse a variável que não tem.

```
<?php
    $url_atual = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $url_source = $_COOKIE['utm_source'] = $_GET['utm_source'];
    $url_medium = $_COOKIE['utm_medium'] = $_GET['utm_medium'];
    $url_campaign = $_COOKIE['utm_campaign'] = $_GET['utm_campaign'];
    $url_term = $_COOKIE['utm_term'] = $_GET['utm_term'];
    $url_content = $_COOKIE['utm_content'] = $_GET['utm_content'];
    if(empty($url_content)) {
        echo 'A variável está vazia';
    }
    else {
        echo 'O valor da variável é: '.$url_content;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Meu site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="enviar-lead.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome:">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail:">
        <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone:">
        <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem:"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="btnContactDefault" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar">

        <input type="hidden" name="source" value="<?=($url_source)?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="medium" value="<?=($url_medium)?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="campaign" value="<?=($url_campaign)?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="term" value="<?=($url_term)?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="content" value="<?=($url_content)?>">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `if` e `isset()` com cada $_GET, esse é o básico da programação "atual", os "Ifs"

Comment: Se faltar um, iria como valor da variável, vazia ?

Comment: Ou poderia usar um ternario retornando o valor nulo.

Comment: @PedroHenrique, poderia ficar vazia. Já consegui. Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma boa pratica fazer validações de variáveis antes de utiliza-las em produção. 
No seu caso, basta colocar um **if** e **else** identificando se há um valor a ser recebido pelo **$_GET.**

Exemplo com ternário pela sintaxe simplificada.

```
    $url_atual = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $url_source = (isset($_GET['utm_source'])) ? $_COOKIE['utm_source'] = $_GET['utm_source'] : null;
    $url_medium = (isset($_GET['utm_medium'])) ? $_COOKIE['utm_medium'] = $_GET['utm_medium'] : null;
    $url_campaign = (isset($_GET['utm_campaign'])) ? $_COOKIE['utm_campaign'] = $_GET['utm_campaign'] : null;
    $url_term = (isset($_GET['utm_term'])) ? $_COOKIE['utm_term'] = $_GET['utm_term'] : null;
    $url_content = (isset($_GET['utm_content'])) ? $_COOKIE['utm_content'] = $_GET['utm_content'] : null;
```

Sintaxe do ternário:

```
$variavel = (condição) ? valor caso a condição seja verdadeira : valor se for falso;
```

Perceba que o parenteses representa a condição do IF, a interrogação (?) representa a resposta verdadeira, e por fim o dois pontos (:) que representa o else quando a condição é falsa.

Comment: Excelente. Obrigado, Glenys +1